# NoClassDefFoundError in Java program execution

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I receive this error when I want to execute my program.
How can I set class path variables for my jar files?  I added them to the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection.<init>(XYSeriesCollection.java:85)
    at xyline.main(xyline.java:22)
```

Comment: Check out details/documentation on classloading for your servlet container. It should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It seems you've fixed your issue, but for future reference, different servlet containers will have a particular way for searching for classes (either in .jar or simply .class files). Using Tomcat as an example, it documents the specific directories that it expects to find code <http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html>. The documentation should also define which directories are particular to all applications hosted by the container, and which direcotries pertain to an individual app. It's worthwhile getting to know your environment. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are deploying a web app to a server within eclipse. You should define how your web app is assembled. Right click the project and go to `Properties > Deployment assembly` and add your classpath entries there.

You need your project to be dynamic web project. For that go to `Properties > Project facets` and select "Dynamic web module". You need WTP (comes with Eclipse for JavaEE)  for that.

Comment: I can't find Deployment assembly in this path.

Comment: your project should be a dynamic web project. go to "Project Facets" and add the dynamic web project facet

Comment: Excuse me @Bozho.where is the dynamic web project facet?I am in this path already.but can't find this option.

Comment: "Dynamic web module", sorry. But you need the Eclipse for JavaEE devleopment (or the WTP plugin by itself)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the path information which is referenced from your jar File.
for that,when you create jar file,in the MANIFEST.MF file, add the following entry.

Class-Path:"Directory-Path\somejar.jar"

This really works.